# Detecting undeclared variables in Scripts

Tags: c#, parsing, variables

I'm using custom script to automate the processes. (Actually learning). This is the script.

```js
var a = 5;
var b = 55;

return a+b;
```

I'm just converting the source to C# and compiling it with CSharpCodeProvider class. I'm currently converting it into tokens and here's my Tokens enum

```cs
public enum Tokens
{
    RETURN,
    NEWLINE,
    WHITESPACE,
    VAR,
    WORD,
    SYMBOL,
    INTEGER
}
```

And am successfully get these tokens

```
VAR, WHITESPACE, WORD, WHITESPACE, INTEGER, SYMBOL
NEWLINE,
VAR, WHITESPACE, WORD, WHITESPACE, INTEGER, SYMBOL
NEWLINE
NEWLINE
RETURN, WHITESPACE, WORD, SYMBOL, WORD, SYMBOL
```

I'm currently trying to find variables which aren't declared and declare them myself. I've tried on adding every `WORD` to the variables list and add it to the script but it gets duplicate declarations.

I want it to also validate

```
a = 5;
var b = 55;

return a+b;
```

i.e only add the declaration for things without a var keyword.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

***EDIT:***

Here's how I'm parsing the source.

```
List<Token> tokensList;
List<string> variables;

for (int i=0; i<tokensList.Count; i++)
{
    Token token = tokensList[i];

    switch (token.TokenType)
    {
        case WORD:
            variables.Add(token.Value);
            break;
    }
    result.Append(token.Value);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by undeclared variables? All of the variables in your script are declared.

Comment: Just trying to get even that case.

Comment: Use a distinct to delete duplcates?

Comment: @Vincenzo How can I do that?

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati you can put it in a dictionary instead of a list, in that case it cannot have duplicates.

Alternatively, replace: "result.Append(token.Value);" with:
if (!result.Contains(token.Value))
result.Append(token.Value);

Comment: I'd use the Linq extensions. Append every time and everything and then get single occurencies using .Distinct method

Comment: @Vincenzo I'm on the .NET 2.0 platform. I can't use linq. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: You can anyway write the function on your own!

Answer (score 0):

you can declare "result" as a Dictionary (=hash), instead of a List,

in that case it cannot have duplicates.

Alternatively, 
replace:

```
   result.Append(token.Value);
```

with:

```
if (!result.Contains(token.Value)) 
        result.Append(token.Value);
```

Comment: Yep. Result is a StringBuilder object. I don't want to add the variables after var keyword to be added.

Comment: Hi, if you'd define it as a String, this syntax (.Contains) will work the same and will have no duplicates.